# What can I do so that RestartDialogEx shows my prompt?

Tags: windows, winapi, reboot

I have a small tool that makes changes to the system and requires a reboot. I use `RestartDialogEx`

```
::RestartDialogEx(NULL, 
                  L"My Question", 
                  EWX_REBOOT, 
                  SHTDN_REASON_MINOR_RECONFIG | SHTDN_REASON_FLAG_PLANNED);
```

But my prompt isn't shown. Only a standard text is used.I can see no comments about this and I can't find any hints that this is a known bug, or what I am doing wrong.

And before some one asks: Yes I adjusted the token privileges first to the call.

Comment: What does `CString(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDP_NEED_REBOOT))` evaluate to? That should really be `CStringW`, too. And a call to `GetString()` doesn't hurt either.

Comment: Yes it evaluates to a CStringW and successfully loads a text. Changed the question "more minimal sample".

Comment: That `_T("...")` should be an `L"..."`.

Comment: Why... ? It works anyway, because it is an unicode project. OK chnages and checked. Didn't worked.

Comment: Why? Because the latter is correct and the former isn't. Both semantically and formally.

Comment: You are right. There is only a Unicode form!

Comment: The [Microsot documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-restartdialogex) mentions: _This function is available through Windows XP Service Pack 2 (SP2) and Windows Server 2003. It might be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions of Windows._ I'd display a dialog of my own rather tha using `RestartDialogEx`

Comment: only option - add # symbol at begin of your string - L"#My Question", but I doubt that you will like how it will be displayed. so or use default text or not use this api